# C Assignment Arrays Error

Tags: c, arrays

The question is: Declare an array of type 'char' called "letters" with a size of 2. Assign the variable "alpha" as the first element of the array "letters".

I tried both:

```
char letters[1];
letters = alpha;
```

and

```
char letters[] = {alpha};
```

The program keeps saying that both of these answers are wrong. What am I doing wrong? Or is an error with the check system?

Comment: Is alpha a single character? Use `letters[0] = alpha;`

Comment: You appears to have misunderstood the application of counting from zero *vis a vis* setting the size of the array. It would be a good idea to read the introductory chapter on arrays in some reference material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first example you are not defining an array of size 2 but of size 1, and (this is the actual error), you're assigning a variable of type char to an array and not to a position of the array...

a simple way:

```
char letters[2]; // array of size 2
char alpha = letters[0]; // assigning the first position of letters array to the alpha variable
```

Comment: Funny: this assigns the first element of the array `letters` to `alpha`, but the question seems to me to ask for the opposite operation (though I grant you the wording is ambiguous — but the attempts certainly imply the opposite): given `char alpha = 'x';` then by initialization `char letters[2] = { alpha, '\0' };` or by assignment `char letters[2] = ""; letters[0] = alpha;`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes in your answer:

- You missed the "of size 2" part,
- The second assignment has to go the other way,
- The first element of the array is at index zero.

You need to add initialization to avoid undefined behavior:

```
char letters[2] = {'x', 'y'};
char alpha = letters[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, using a 1 instead of a 2 should have tipped you off.  And if you want to assign to an element of letters, you probably need to say something more than just the name.